# Create synonym for a function in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am unable to use synonym for a function in Oracle with below query. I have created synonyms with below query:
Create or replace synonym "schema1"."function1" for "schema2"."function2"

But when I try to use this synonym then I get below error:
ORA-00904: "function1": invalid identifier

Do I  have to pass parameters as well while creating synonym for a function?

Comment: If, by "below query" you mean the 'create or replace synonym ....' statement that you provided, my first guess would be that you wrapped your object names in double-quotes, thus making the reference case sensitive.  Perhaps you actually have a function named FUNCTION2 (upper case in the data dictionary) belonging to SCHEMA2 (again, upper-case in the dictionary), but by wrapping them in double-quotes, you are forcing the reference to be case sensitive.  In the oracle world, use of double-quotes is generally a very bad idea.

Comment: @EdStevens I am new to Oracle so I didn't know that wrapping objects makes them case sensitive. I just removed double quotes and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) documentation:

> ## Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

...

> - Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.
>
>   By enclosing names in double quotation marks, you can give the following names to different objects in the same namespace:
>
>   ```
>   "employees"
>   "Employees"
>   "EMPLOYEES"
>   ```
>
>   Note that Oracle interprets the following names the same, so they cannot be used for different objects in the same namespace:
>
>   ```
>   employees
>   EMPLOYEES
>   "EMPLOYEES"
>   ```

If you have created your function using:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION schema1.function1 /* (...) */ RETURNING NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Then your function uses non-quoted identifiers and its identifier will be converted to upper-case in the data dictionary.

You can then refer to your function using:

```
"SCHEMA1"."FUNCTION1"
SCHEMA1.FUNCTION1
schema1.function1
ScHeMa1."FUNCTION1"
scheMa1.FUNCtion1
```

Etc. provided that quoted identifiers are in upper-case and non-quoted identifiers can have any case.

However, `"schema1"."function1"` would fail as the object is called `"SCHEMA1"."FUNCTION1"` and, by using quoted identifiers, you are forcing case-senstivity in the identifiers (rather than the default behaviour of implicitly converting non-quoted identifiers to upper case and then case sensitivity is not an issue).

---

If you have created the schema and the function both using lower-case quoted identifiers (don't do this, its bad practice) then you will have to **ALWAYS** refer to them using quoted identifiers with exactly the same case.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION "schema1"."function1" /* (...) */ RETURNING NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Then you can only ever refer to it using:

```
"schema1"."function1"
```

And (assuming you have the permissions to create a synonym) then your code should work.